# Adb command for call sim2

Tags: android, adb

I want to call by sim2 using adb command (Dual sim state)

This is call using adb command
but default call is only sim1

adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d 123-4567

Is there an adb command to change the default call in a dual sim situation?

call by sim2 setting using adb command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `sim_slot` as follows :

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:<phone_number> --es sim_slot "1"
```

Where "1" corresponds to SIM 2.

Comment: It's not working .
If call setting was sim1 , It command only call for sim1. Is there have command for change call state sim1 to sim2 ??

Comment: Using the `--es sim_slot "1"` also uses sim1?

Comment: yes device only call for setting sim slot

Comment: Do you have the ADB set-up on your computer and in debug-mode?

Comment: yes enable debug mode

Answer (score 0):

To find out the current ID value run:

```
adb shell settings get global multi_sim_voice_call
```

Use this command to switch to the appropriate ID before calling:

```
adb shell settings put global multi_sim_voice_call <ID>
```

Comment: This can be change call sim slot but need to reboot the device . 
Is there have command not reboot??